# Tool to build graph with class dependencies in java

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, static-analysis

I'm looking for a way to visualize the dependencies between classes in java and to possibly integrate this during build using gradle.

To provide an example I'm looking for a tool that in the following situation

```
class a{
    int a1;
    public function a2(){b bclass = new b();}
}
```

it will show that class a depends on class b.

What I'm trying to gain is to visualize how complex the design is and how we can simplify it.

Comment: Depending on how decoupled the project classes are, this might be quite a feat to accomplish.

Comment: Well, even checking the imports and parsing the code for the names of other classes should be fairly easy. Actually, I can probably write a script to do this, just grep each *.java  for the filenames of every other *.java, if you find anything add a dependency. But I'd like to find something cleaner than my quick n dirty scripts

Answer (score 1):

If a class depends on classes from different packages you could easily get list of imports using grep (unfortunately you can't use reflection here). Though finding out dependency classes residing in the same package would be a bit complex.